# Host Name (Server Name?) is Different from the Computer Name

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, workstation

I have done a network scan on my network.  In the results some of the computers have Host Names that are the same as the "Computer Name" and some have names that are not their respected computer names.  For example.  The computer name of the computer (Win7) is `PC1` and the HOST NAME (from the scanner) is `filer-cli.storage`.   This computer is on a Workgroup not a domain.  I do Not have a DNS server on the network.  I have no idea where this name comes from and I do not know how to get rid of it.

- IPCONFIG - Host Name is PC1;
- NBTSTAT -A 192.168.1.100 - Name is PC1;
- NSLOOKUP 192.168.1.100 - nslookup  Server: Unknown, Address = My router address-192.168.1.1, Name=filer-cli.storage, Address: <192.168.1.100>,  Aliases:4.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa.

Any idea on How I can get rid of this name I am getting from the NSLOOKUP. Where is is coming from? Thanks guys, I am at a Loss.

Comment: Generally, whatever is after the `.` [`.storage`] is the local domain name set for the LAN on the router. _(While not relevant to this question, in Windows, this should be set as the WorkGroup name since Windows uses the WorkGroup name as the local domain name - this especially matters when accessing network shares by DNS name and not IP.)_ For example, `nslookup` will display the Server/Name as `<hostname>.<LocalDomainName>` for the respective device. What does Windows return via `hostname`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your scanner appending the router name filer-cli.storage with each host name on scanning. Since you don't have a dedicated DNS server in your network,and your router acting as DNS server, this appending router name and shown as FQDN pc1.filer-cli.storage.

This can be avoid by two ways, either put DNS Suffix as filer-cli.storage in each hosts or remove the router name filer-cli.storage from router configuration if possible. Run the scanner again and update the result.